# Blazor Selectable

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

So I found [this Selectable library in JQuery](https://jqueryui.com/selectable/#display-grid) but I've found no counterpart in Blazor, is there such a thing or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine Right, but it's not just the clicked part, it's the drag to select with a square / rectangle that I'm looking for. Click / CTRL + Click would be easy.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such component in Blazor. There is also none like that in MudBlazor or Telerik. The feature of selecting by dragging the mouse is not very common in these frameworks.

You can simply use your favorite library via JQuery in your Blazor application if you don't mind including JQuery in your project.

The easiest way to integrate other libraries to your Blazor application is to insert the result of your library into a field that you have in Blazor and from there use the standard event handlers in Blazor.